# Adding infinite translate and rotate (with different speeds) animations to one element

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate some shapes made with CSS-Doodle which will be a part of my background. Basically, I want them to always float around the screen and always rotate but I want the two animations at different speeds.

With the code below I can only get either one to work by switching around the order of chaining.

animation: spin @r(3s, 10s) infinite, flow @r(20s, 40s) infinite linear;

```
@keyframes flow {
  0%, 100%{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)   
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(@r(-500%, 1000%), @r(-500%, 1000%), 0);  
    transform: translate3d(@r(-500%, 1000%), @r(-500%, 1000%), 0);       
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from  {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }   
}
```

I'm hoping there's a way for both of them to be applied at the same time even if it's not pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way but the simplest solution would be to put a wrapper around the element so that the wrapper gets one animation and the actual element gets the other animation.

Comment: Thanks! While this means that all shapes rotate around a shared axis and not their own, it still works for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you need to change the axis you can add the transform-origin property (although depending on the number of things you are animating that could be a bit labor intensive): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: @mowie: If this solves you problem, mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I wasn't aware of that property. I'm working with a lot of shapes right now but I'm sure I'll find it very useful in the future!